# Regular $T_2$ space which is not completely regular.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Theorem 10. of 
Pontryagin's *Topological Groups* says that:

> Every Hausdorff topological group is completely regular.

But is there exists a Regular $T_2$ space which is not completely regular?

Comment: Hi, TXC, I find some counterexamples, which may be helpful for you.

Comment: @Paul: Tnx a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/386811/12042) has a complete description of such a space, due to John Thomas and published in *A Regular Space, Not Completely Regular*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 76, No. 2 (Feb., 1969), pp. 181-182.

Comment: Your responses are very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TXC: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

These are counterexamples, which may be hepful for you:

> [Deleted Tychonoff Corkscrew](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [Hewitt’s Condensed Corkscrew](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [Thomas’s Corkscrew](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [Tychonoff Corkscrew](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)