# If $X$ is a totally disconnected space, then is $\beta(X)$ totally disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, compactification

I know that when $X$ is a normal and totally disconnected space, the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta(X)$ is totally disconnected. But I can't find a counterexample when considering $X$ totally disconnected only.

Comment: Is $\beta$ a continuous function?

Comment: No. Is a functor. $\beta(X) is the Stone-Cech compactification for X. Excuse me

Comment: Are there any particular examples, you have checked? or suspect might work?

Comment: For example when $X$ is a discrete space, $\beta(X)$  is totally disconnected

Comment: Do you assume $X$ is at least completely regular, so it embeds in $\beta(X)$?

Comment: No. I'm thinking $X$ like a general  topological space

Answer (score 4):

No.  Any totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space is zero-dimensional (clopen sets generate the topology), and any subspace of a zero-dimensional space is zero-dimensional.  So, if $X$ is completely regular and $\beta(X)$ is totally disconnected, then $X$ must be zero-dimensional.  This means any completely regular space which is totally disconnected but not zero-dimensional is a counterexample.  Such a space is complicated to construct but one well-known example is [Cantor's teepee](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000126/properties/P000067) (also known as the deleted Knaster-Kuratowski fan).  Note that this example is also normal (it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$), so your statement about the case that $X$ is normal is incorrect.

Comment: I believe that $\beta X$ is zero-dimensional iff $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional. See Engelking.

Comment: Is possible to remove the assumption of X completely regular?

Comment: Seems very unlikely.  I haven't checked the details but I suspect the construction I describe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3371147/86856) gives a counterexample: if you take a Cantor set and enlarge its topology to make a countable dense set open, it will no longer be zero-dimensional, but I think its Stone-Cech compactification will still be the original Cantor set.

Comment: I'll work about your hint, thank you so much. Can I do an other question? I'd like  ask you about hint for to prove your afirmation : Any totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space is zero-dimensional (clopen sets generate the topology)

Comment: It suffices to show the topology generated by the clopen sets is Hausdorff, by compactness (you cannot have a compact topology that is strictly finer than a Hausdorff topology).  In other words, you need to show that clopen sets separate points; for that see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11412/any-two-points-in-a-stone-space-can-be-disconnected-by-clopen-sets

Comment: Erdős' space $E = \{(x_n)_n \in \ell^2\mid \forall n: x_n \in \Bbb Q\}$ in the subspace topology from $\ell^2$ is separable metric, $\dim(E)=1$ (and $E \times E \simeq E$, so dimensions don't add up in products in general) and $E$ is totally disconnected. A bit of a late addition...