# Existence of a continuous function which does not achieve a maximum.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

> Suppose $X$ is a non-compact metric space. Show that there exists a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ does not achieve a maximum.

I proved this assertion as follows:

If $X$ is non-compact, there exists a sequence which has no converging subsequence. Therefore, the set $E$ of elements of this sequence is infinite and has no limit points. Therefore, in the induced topology, $E$ is a countable discrete space. Let $e_n$ be a enumeration of $E$. Define $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(e_n)=n$. Since $E$ is discrete, $f$ is continuous. By Tietze (note that $E$ is closed in $X$), there exists a continuous function $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which extends $f$. But $f$ is unbounded, then so is $g$, and $g$ does not achieve a maximum. $\square$

My first question is: Is everything in the proof fine?

Now, my second question is: Can you provide me a proof which is more elementary? (Not using Tietze, for example. This exercise is just after the definition of compactness. I suppose this proof is not what was intended.)

And my third question is: Does the proposition hold for arbitrary topological spaces? If not, can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: Assume that on $\mathbb{N}$ we put the topology in which the open sets are $\emptyset$ and all subsets that contain $0$. A continuous function on this space is constant (equal to $f(0)$) and therefore bounded. But the open cover $\{[0,n]\}_n$ doesn't have finite subcovers.

Comment: "Arbitrary topological spaces" -- real-valued functions on finite spaces always achieve maxima :-)

Comment: May i ask you a question that is really similar to this one? I'm interested in proving that if $X$ is not compact then exists $g: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which does not have positive infimum. Following your proof, it is the same until when we have to define $f$. I chose to define $f(e_n)=1/n$. This would imply $\inf f(X)=0$. But does this also imply that the extesion $g$ also does not have a positive infimum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument is correct and is probably the most straightforward. The result does not even hold in all $T_3$ spaces: in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047452/12042) I give a general method, due to Eric van Douwen, for starting with a $T_3$ space  having two points that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function and producing from it a $T_3$ space on which all continuous real-valued functions are constant. The other answer to that question gives references to two $T_3$ spaces having two points that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/386811/12042) expands on one of those spaces and gives yet another example of such a space.

Comment: A Little bit off Topic but is your $T_3$ necessarily Hausdorff?

Comment: @Domenic: Yes: $T_k$ implies $T_\ell$ whenever $k\ge\ell$.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an explicit and elementary construction, using only the fact that a metric space is compact iff every sequence has an accumulation point.  Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ with no accumulation point, and define $g(x)=\inf_n d(x,x_n)+1/n$ and $f(x)=1/g(x)$.  It is easy to see that $g(x)=0$ iff $x$ is an accumulation point of $(x_n)$, so $g$ is never $0$ and $f$ is defined on all of $X$.  Moreover, $f(x_n)\geq n$, so $f$ is unbounded.  Finally, it is straightforward to check that $g$ is continuous, and hence so is $f$.

Answer (score 4):

The proof seems fine but Tietze needs to have the function continuous on a closed subset, but as it has no limit points this is given. If your function Needs to be continuous I can tell you the third question to have a negative answer.

In fact there is a non compact Hausdorff space such that the continuous functions are exactly the constant ones. Take $\mathbb{Z}^+$ with the relatively prime integer topology, here it is the case that for every non empty open sets $U,V$ the intersection $\overline{U}\cap \overline{V}\neq \varnothing$ hence every continuous function to $\mathbb{R}$ must be constant and so surely attains a Maximum. 
To see it is not compact is a bit more difficult, here you use that if it is compact it needs to be $T_3$ and $T_4$ (as it is Hausdorff), but with $T_4$ we would have Urysohn-Lemma which grants you more continuous mappings.